# generating graph using google API in java

Tags: javascript, java, graph, google-api

I am trying to create graph for 'sale v/s return' in my project. I am using google API with Java and data from DB. My code is as below,

JS code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTrendlines);

function drawTrendlines() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sale');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Return');
    var bb="BPS40L 1 Y";
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "chart?icd="+bb+"&opt="+1,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: "day"
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: "Sales"
        },
        colors: ['#AB0D06', '#007329'],
        trendlines: {
            0: {type: 'exponential', color: '#333', opacity: 1},
            1: {type: 'linear', color: '#111', opacity: .3}
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options, {width: 600, height: 540});
}
});
```

Java Code:

```
ArrayList mn1 = new ArrayList();
while (rs.next()) {
    JSONObject aListcounter = new JSONObject();
    aListcounter.put(i,i);
    aListcounter.put("sale",rs.getInt("SLQ"));
    aListcounter.put("return",rs.getInt("RTQ"));
    mn1.add(aListcounter);
    i+=3;
} 
rs.close();
ps.close();
response.setContentType("application/json");
//new Gson().toJson(list2, response.getWriter());
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.put("data",mn1);

out.println(mn1);
```

I am getting output from server as below:

```
[{"0":0,"sale":"3","return":"13"},{"1":1,"sale":"23","return":"23"}]
```

No graph is generated. Getting error message: "`not an array`"

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the data sent by the server so it has this format:

```
[
  ["X", "Sale", "Return"],
  [0, 3, 13],
  [1, 23, 23]
]
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTrendlines);

function drawTrendlines() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sale');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Return');
  var bb = "BPS40L 1 Y";
  var jsonData = 
  [
    ["X", "Sale", "Return"],
    [0, 3, 13],
    [1, 23, 23]
  ];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: "day"
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: "Sales"
    },
    colors: ['#AB0D06', '#007329'],
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        type: 'exponential',
        color: '#333',
        opacity: 1
      },
      1: {
        type: 'linear',
        color: '#111',
        opacity: .3
      }
    }
  };

  var chart =
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options, {
    width: 600,
    height: 540
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to know how to pass and receive from server side using java.

Comment: I don't understand. What you need to do is fix your Java code, for instance by using `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`, so that it produces the output I posted at the top of my answer. What does "how to pass and receive from server" have to do with this question?